# Подключение библиотек внутри namespace

Tags: c#, .net

Часто замечаю код где библиотеки подключаются не перед `namespace`, а внутри. Интересно почему так делают и какие принципиальные различия?

Привычный способ подключения:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
namespace Domain 
{ 

}
```

Способ подключения внутри `namespace`:

```
namespace Domain
{
    using System;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/125319/276994

Comment: @VladD, а перевести? ;-)

Comment: @VladD, Впринципе все понятно, но мне кажется кто-то на русском хотел бы почитать.

Comment: @Lightness: Я бы перевёл, но сваливаю в отпуск примерно через 5 минут :) Пусть кто-то ещё напишет хороший ответ по теме.

Comment: @VladD, я занялся :-) но может кто-то раньше успеет :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Перевод ответа на [аналогичный вопрос на английском](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/125319/should-using-statements-be-inside-or-outside-the-namespace)

Разница действительно есть.
Представим, что есть файл *File1.cs* со следующим кодом:

```
// File1.cs
using System;
namespace Outer.Inner
{
    class Foo
    {
        static void Bar()
        {
            double d = Math.PI;
        }
    }
}
```

Теперь представим, что кто-то добавил еще один файл (*File2.cs*):

```
// File2.cs
namespace Outer
{
    class Math
    {
    }
}
```

Компилятор найдет `Outer` до того как просмотрит `using` вне пространства имен, поэтому он найдет `Outer.Math` вместо `System.Math`. К несчастью (или возможно к счастью?), в `Outer.Math` нет члена `PI`, поэтому компилятор начнет ругаться на `Math.PI` в файле *File1.cs*.

Все поменяется, если поместить `using` внутрь определения пространства имен, например так:

```
// File1b.cs
namespace Outer.Inner
{
    using System;
    class Foo
    {
        static void Bar()
        {
            double d = Math.PI;
        }
    }
}
```

Теперь компилятор найдет `System` до `Outer`, и будет использовать `System.Math`, и все будет хорошо.

Некоторые утверждают, что `Math` это плохое имя для пользовательского класса, потому что такой класс уже есть в `System`; дело в том, что только здесь есть разница и это отразится на сопровождаемости кода.

Также интересно, что может случиться, если `Foo` будет объявлен в пространстве имен`Outer`, а не `Outer.Inner`. В этом случае, добавление `Outer.Math` в *File2* ломает *File1* независимо от того, где расположены `using`. Это означает, что компилятор ищет в самом внутреннем пространстве имен, прежде чем смотреть в любых выражениях `using`.

Answer (score 6):

Перевод, одного из ответов [Should 'using' statements be inside or outside the namespace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/125319/should-using-statements-be-inside-or-outside-the-namespace)

Для начала обратим внимание на тот факт, что пространство имен определенное вот таким образом:

```
namespace MyCorp.TheProduct.SomeModule.Utilities
{
    ...
}
```

эквивалентно определению нескольких вложенных пространств имен:

```
namespace MyCorp
{
    namespace TheProduct
    {
        namespace SomeModule
        {
            namespace Utilities
            {
                ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Если вы подключает сборку вне пространства, то она будет видна внутри всех охватывающих пространств. Правило поиска конкретного типа можно выразить примерно так: **во-первых поиск совпадения в самой внутренней "области видимости", если ничего не нашли там выйти на один уровень вверх и искать там, и так далее, пока не будет найдено совпадение. Если на каком-то уровне встречается более чем одно совпадение, вы получите предупреждение компилятора. Если не найдено, выдать ошибку на этапе компиляции.**

Теперь, давайте более четко о том, что это означает, на конкретном примере с двумя основными конвенциями.

**(1) С usings снаружи:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
//using MyCorp.TheProduct;  <-- uncommenting this would change nothing
using MyCorp.TheProduct.OtherModule;
using MyCorp.TheProduct.OtherModule.Integration;
using ThirdParty;

namespace MyCorp.TheProduct.SomeModule.Utilities
{
    class C
    {
        Ambiguous a;
    }
}
```

В приведенном случае, чтобы выяснить тип `Ambiguous`, поиск идет в следующем порядке:

1. Вложенные типы внутри `C` (включая унаследованные вложенные типы)
2. Типы в текущем пространстве имен `MyCorp.TheProduct.SomeModule.Utilities`
3. Типы в пространстве имен `MyCorp.TheProduct.SomeModule`
4. Типы в `MyCorp.TheProduct`
5. Типы в `MyCorp`
6. Типы в глобальном пространстве имен
7. Типы в `System`, `System.Collections.Generic`, `System.Linq`, `MyCorp.TheProduct.OtherModule`, `MyCorp.TheProduct.OtherModule.Integration` и `ThirdParty`

Другая конвенция:

**(2) С usings внутри:**

```
namespace MyCorp.TheProduct.SomeModule.Utilities
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using MyCorp.TheProduct;                           // MyCorp can be left out; this using is NOT redundant
    using MyCorp.TheProduct.OtherModule;               // MyCorp.TheProduct can be left out
    using MyCorp.TheProduct.OtherModule.Integration;   // MyCorp.TheProduct can be left out
    using ThirdParty;

    class C
    {
        Ambiguous a;
    }
}
```

Теперь поиск по типу `Ambiguous` идет в следующем порядке:

1. Вложенные типы внутри `C` (включая унаследованные вложенные типы)
2. Типы в текущем пространстве имен `MyCorp.TheProduct.SomeModule.Utilities`
3. Типы в `System`, `System.Collections.Generic`, `System.Linq`, `MyCorp.TheProduct` , `MyCorp.TheProduct.OtherModule`,  `MyCorp.TheProduct.OtherModule.Integration` и `ThirdParty`
4. Типы в пространстве имен `MyCorp.TheProduct.SomeModule`
5. Типы в `MyCorp`
6. Типы в глобальном пространстве имен

(Обратите внимание , что `MyCorp.TheProduct` был частью "3." и, следовательно , не требуется между "4." и "5".)

**Заключительные замечания**

Независимо от того, помещаете вы `using` внутри или вне объявления пространства имен, всегда есть вероятность того, что кто-то позже добавит новый тип с идентичным именем к одному из пространств, которое имеет более высокий приоритет.

Кроме того, если вложенное пространство имен имеет то же имя, что и тип, это может вызвать проблемы.

Всегда опасно перемещение `using` из одного места в другое, так как иерархия поиска изменяется, и может быть найден другой тип. Поэтому выберите одну конвенцию и придерживайтесь ее, что бы вам не пришлось когда-либо двигать `using`.

Шаблоном `Visual Studio`, по умолчанию, является `using` вне пространства имен (например , если вы создате новый класс в новом файле).

Одно (крошечное) преимущество наличия `using` вне пространства имен,  вы можете использовать директивы для глобального атрибута, например 
`[assembly: ComVisible(false)]` вместо `[assembly: System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComVisible(false)]` .

Comment: а поправить ошибки автоматического перевода? а то как то совсем не по-русски местами, буквы и слова правильные, а текст при этом корявый.